# How to start expressjs(nodejs) as production mode

Tags: node.js, express, mean-stack

I want to start my express server in production mode. I have tried running it with following command

```
sudo NODE_ENV=production node server.js
```

while

```
sudo node server.js
```

starts my server in development mode with out any problem. First command starts the server in production mode but homepage opens blank with black bar on top. I have 2 request fail

```
Request URL:http://localhost:3000/public/build/js/dist.min.js
Request Method:GET
Status Code:404 Not Found\

Request URL:http://localhost:3000/public/build/css/dist.min.css
Request Method:GET
Status Code:404 Not Found
```

I indeed have all requests getting success in development mode. I couldnt figure out the source for these requests, while there is no such files or request in development mode. I am working on boiler plate code of [mean.io](http://mean.io/) .

```
//server/config/config.js
'use strict';

// Utilize Lo-Dash utility library
var _ = require('lodash'),
    fs = require('fs');

// Load configurations
// Set the node environment variable if not set before
process.env.NODE_ENV = ~fs.readdirSync('./server/config/env').map(function(file) {
    return file.slice(0, -3);
}).indexOf(process.env.NODE_ENV) ? process.env.NODE_ENV : 'development';

// Extend the base configuration in all.js with environment
// specific configuration
module.exports = _.extend(
    require('./env/all'),
    require('./env/' + process.env.NODE_ENV) || {}
);
```

Following is express.js

```
//server/config/express.js
'use strict';

/**
 * Module dependencies.
 */
var express = require('express'),
    favicon = require('static-favicon'),
    morgan = require('morgan'),
    compression = require('compression'),
    bodyParser = require('body-parser'),
    methodOverride = require('method-override'),
    cookieParser = require('cookie-parser'),
    session = require('express-session'),
    errorHandler = require('errorhandler'),
    mean = require('meanio'),
    consolidate = require('consolidate'),
    mongoStore = require('mean-connect-mongo')(session),
    flash = require('connect-flash'),
    helpers = require('view-helpers'),
    config = require('./config'),
    expressValidator = require('express-validator'),
    appPath = process.cwd(),
    util = require('./util'),
    assetmanager = require('assetmanager'),
    fs = require('fs'),
    Grid = require('gridfs-stream');

module.exports = function(app, passport, db) {

    var gfs = new Grid(db.connections[0].db, db.mongo);

    app.set('showStackError', true);

    // Prettify HTML
    app.locals.pretty = true;

    // cache=memory or swig dies in NODE_ENV=production
    app.locals.cache = 'memory';

    // Should be placed before express.static
    // To ensure that all assets and data are compressed (utilize bandwidth)
    app.use(compression({
        // Levels are specified in a range of 0 to 9, where-as 0 is
        // no compression and 9 is best compression, but slowest
        level: 9
    }));

    // Only use logger for development environment
    if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') {
        app.use(morgan('dev'));
    }

    // assign the template engine to .html files
    app.engine('html', consolidate[config.templateEngine]);

    // set .html as the default extension
    app.set('view engine', 'html');

    // Set views path, template engine and default layout
    app.set('views', config.root + '/server/views');

    // Enable jsonp
    app.enable('jsonp callback');

    // The cookieParser should be above session
    app.use(cookieParser());

    // Request body parsing middleware should be above methodOverride
    app.use(expressValidator());
    app.use(bodyParser());
    app.use(methodOverride());
    app.use(cookieParser());

    // Import your asset file
    var assets = require('./assets.json');
    assetmanager.init({
        js: assets.js,
        css: assets.css,
        debug: (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production'),
        webroot: 'public/public'
    });

    // Add assets to local variables
    app.use(function(req, res, next) {
        res.locals.assets = assetmanager.assets;
        next();
    });

    // Express/Mongo session storage
    app.use(session({
        secret: config.sessionSecret,
        store: new mongoStore({
            db: db.connection.db,
            collection: config.sessionCollection
        })
    }));

    // Dynamic helpers
    app.use(helpers(config.app.name));

    // Use passport session
    app.use(passport.initialize());
    app.use(passport.session());

    //mean middleware from modules before routes
    app.use(mean.chainware.before);

    // Connect flash for flash messages
    app.use(flash());

    // Setting the fav icon and static folder
    app.use(favicon());

    app.get('/modules/aggregated.js', function(req, res) {
        res.setHeader('content-type', 'text/javascript');
        res.send(mean.aggregated.js);
    });

    function themeHandler(req, res) {

        res.setHeader('content-type', 'text/css');

        gfs.files.findOne({
            filename: 'theme.css'
        }, function(err, file) {

            if (!file) {
                fs.createReadStream(process.cwd() + '/public/system/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css').pipe(res);
            } else {
                // streaming to gridfs
                var readstream = gfs.createReadStream({
                    filename: 'theme.css'
                });

                //error handling, e.g. file does not exist
                readstream.on('error', function(err) {
                    console.log('An error occurred!', err.message);
                    throw err;
                });

                readstream.pipe(res);
            }
        });
    }

    // We override this file to allow us to swap themes
    // We keep the same public path so we can make use of the bootstrap assets
    app.get('/public/system/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css', themeHandler);

    app.get('/modules/aggregated.css', function(req, res) {
        res.setHeader('content-type', 'text/css');
        res.send(mean.aggregated.css);
    });

    app.use('/public', express.static(config.root + '/public'));

    mean.events.on('modulesFound', function() {

        for (var name in mean.modules) {
            app.use('/' + name, express.static(config.root + '/' + mean.modules[name].source + '/' + name + '/public'));
        }

        function bootstrapRoutes() {
            // Skip the app/routes/middlewares directory as it is meant to be
            // used and shared by routes as further middlewares and is not a
            // route by itself
            util.walk(appPath + '/server/routes', 'middlewares', function(path) {
                require(path)(app, passport);
            });
        }

        bootstrapRoutes();

        //mean middlware from modules after routes
        app.use(mean.chainware.after);

        // Assume "not found" in the error msgs is a 404. this is somewhat
        // silly, but valid, you can do whatever you like, set properties,
        // use instanceof etc.
        app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
            // Treat as 404
            if (~err.message.indexOf('not found')) return next();

            // Log it
            console.error(err.stack);

            // Error page
            res.status(500).render('500', {
                error: err.stack
            });
        });

        // Assume 404 since no middleware responded
        app.use(function(req, res) {
            res.status(404).render('404', {
                url: req.originalUrl,
                error: 'Not found'
            });
        });

        // Error handler - has to be last
        if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') {
            app.use(errorHandler());
        }
    });
};
```

I did not make changes in either of the above files after starting from code from mean.io.
[image: production mode]

Comment: Give us your code please...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is solved by running following commands before starting server

```
grunt cssmin
grunt uglify
```